# Warnings while building Scala/Spark project with SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to build a Scala/Spark project in IntelliJ Idea with the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "try"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache-snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion
)
```

and getting a bunch of warnings:

```
8/6/17
1:29 PM SBT project import
                [warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
                [warn]  * io.netty:netty:3.9.9.Final is selected over {3.6.2.Final, 3.7.0.Final}
                [warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0             (depends on 3.9.9.Final)
                [warn]      +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6               (depends on 3.6.2.Final)
                [warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.6.5                (depends on 3.6.2.Final)
                [warn]  * commons-net:commons-net:2.2 is selected over 3.1
                [warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0             (depends on 2.2)
                [warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.5              (depends on 3.1)
                [warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 is selected over {12.0.1, 16.0.1}
                [warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:2.6.5         (depends on 11.0.2)
                [warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:2.6.5            (depends on 11.0.2)
                [warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:2.6.5
```

I have several, perhaps dumb, questions:

1. Is there a better way to structure `build.sbt` (add other resolvers e.g.?), so that I can get rid off the warnings?
2. Should I care about warnings at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is there a better way to structure build.sbt (add other resolvers e.g.?), so that I can get rid off the warnings?

One way is to manually tell sbt what dependencies you prefer, for your case:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.9.Final",
  "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "2.2",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "11.0.2"
)
```

I also recommend reading about [conflict management in sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Conflict+Management).

> Should I care about warnings at all?

In your case - no, since your conflicts stem from using only spark-related artifacts released under same version. Spark is a project with big userbase and possibility of jar hell introduced due to transitive dependencies is rather low (although, technically not guaranteed).

In general case - maybe. Typically it is ok in most of the cases, but there is a small possibility of a problem that may need careful manual dependency resolution (if this is possible at all). In these cases it is really hard to tell whether there is a problem before you run your app and bump into some problem like missing class, method, mismatching method signature or some reflection-related problem.

Comment: Good answer. I am also wondering every time I encounter such warning why some lib creators declare lib dependencies in a way that produces such warnings. When I see this I am thinking "guys, have you tried to build your own project in SBT? Have not you seen these warnings?" :)

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for the effort, but my SBT built is still failing (see log in the UPDATE). Any ideas?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: Use `"io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.9.Final"`, then run `reload` and `update` in your `sbt` console.

Comment: @chunjef Thanks, now it's working!!! Eugene Loy, can you please update your answer and I will accept it???

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov done. It was inaccuracy on my part, sorry for that. BTW, I think it is better to remove edit related to netty versioning in your opening post to simplify experience for those who seek answer to your original question. I don't think this small hiccup related to versioning is that relevant to solving the original problem and only adds unnecessary details.

Comment: @chunje thanks for pointing this out. I missed this uncommon netty versioning scheme.

Comment: If I am right it should be `dependencyOverrides ++= Seq()` not Set as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In `sbt`, Spark is normally listed as a `Provided` dependency, i.e.,

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided
```

You may be pulling in unnecessary and conflicting recursive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works fine, you can disable these warnings by adding this to build settings:

```
evictionWarningOptions in update := EvictionWarningOptions.default
.withWarnTransitiveEvictions(false)
```